# Backtracking a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am learning and having much fun with python, currently I am making a simple discord bot but I am stuck with nested dictionary access problem.

This is my command

```
@bot.command()
async def burek(ctx, arg):

    burek_seller = burek_dictionary["bureks"][arg]["seller"]
    burek_price = burek_dictionary["bureks"][arg]["price"]
    burek_state = burek_dictionary["bureks"][arg]["state"]
    burek_name = burek_dictionary["bureks"][arg]["name"]

    await ctx.send(
        f"{burek_name} is available {burek_state} at {burek_seller} for {burek_price}$."
    )
```

The problem is I want to change 'arg' to search by 'name' in my nested dictionary not by a number of nested dictionary. I am aware I will have to make a few changes, but I have been stuck trying to figure it out for two days now :(

this is my dictionary

```
burek_dictionary = {
    "bureks": {
        "0": {
            "name": "mesni",
            "ingredient": "govedina",
            "seller": "sipac",
            "price": 2.2,
            "state": "hot",
            "demand": "low",
        },
        "1": {
            "name": "sirni",
            "ingredient": "sir",
            "seller": "merc",
            "price": 1.8,
            "state": "cold",
            "demand": "average",
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "spinacni",
            "ingredient": "spinaca",
            "seller": "pecjak",
            "price": 2,
            "state": "fresh",
            "demand": "high",
        },
        "3": {
            "name": "ajdov",
            "ingredient": "sirspinaca",
            "price": 2.1,
            "state": "hot",
            "demand": "average",
        },
    }
}
```

Obviously now as 'arg' I have to write a number to achieve my result, but I would like to use 'name' from dictionary and achieve the same result. I have no idea idea how to approach this. I hope it makes sense! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

Loop through the bureks and when you find the one with the matching name, use that.

I assume you might need the same functionality somewhere else, so I broke it out into a separate function.

```
def find_burek_by_name(name):
    for burek_key, burek_info in burek_dictionary["bureks"].items():
        if burek_info["name"] == name:
            return burek_info
    return None  # Not found


@bot.command()
async def burek(ctx, arg):
    burek_info = find_burek_by_name(arg)
    if burek_info:
        burek_seller = burek_info["seller"]
        burek_price = burek_info["price"]
        burek_state = burek_info["state"]
        burek_name = burek_info["name"]

        await ctx.send(
            f"{burek_name} is available {burek_state} at {burek_seller} for {burek_price}$."
        )
    else:
        pass  # No such burek
```

Comment: Thank you very much this works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the entire dictionary beforehand, you can build a map from names to numbers, if the dict does not change you build the map in a single pass and avoid looping later:

```
name2num = {}
for num in burek_dictionary["bureks"]:
    name2num[burek_dictionary["bureks"][num]["name"]] = num
print(name2num)

name = "sirni"
num = name2num[name]
burek_seller = burek_dictionary["bureks"][num]["seller"]
burek_price = burek_dictionary["bureks"][num]["price"]
burek_state = burek_dictionary["bureks"][num]["state"]
burek_name = burek_dictionary["bureks"][num]["name"]
print(burek_seller, burek_price, burek_state, burek_name)
```

Cheers!